# light up keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard

i have a pi 4 and recently got a new MFTEK keyboard and mouse. both are working and light up when plugged into a laptop. when i connect the keyboard in the pi, it doesn't light up (still works as a normal keyboard) though the mouse does. to turn the lights on, you press 'scroll lock' but again once plugged in the pi, it doesn't turn on. anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: yes, install the necessary drivers ... your question is off topic here because it is about Linux, not about Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unplugging and replugging your keyboard? And if the keyboard did not come with batteries, maybe there's another battery spot for the lights? Hope this helps.

Comment: The question does say "plugged into" several times, so it is not battery powered at all.

Answer (score 0):

From your statement the keyboard works as intended. I expect you have a power problem with the Pi. This is based on the information I found stating it does not need a driver.  The USB port should give you 5V with the keyboard plugged in.

I got this from the Newegg site: "Compatible System??: USB wired?? no driver need?? compatible with Windows10?? Windows 8?? Windows 7?? Windows XP?? Mac OS X?? Windows XP?? Windows Vista; IBM/PC Laptop/PS4/Xbox/Mac OS. We provide Lifetime ??FREE Returns & Exchanges and Refund money back?? for any quality problem." It also states: "RGB gaming keyboard with vivid rainbow color backlit mode and breathing mode?? you can press
Fn+SL: **Backlit switch On/Off;**"   What does your vendor say about the problem.